# Drive a 12V pump do I need a l293 driver

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

Me and my girlfriend are working on a small automatic plant watering system. Our first goal is to make an electrical 12V pump suck water out of a bottle.

As we were reading tutorials online we noticed that many people hook up a driver such as the l293 to their arduino in order to control the pump (essentially a brushed DC motor).

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293.pdf

Our pump is 12V 4.2 W.

My question is do we really need a driver like that for just activating / deactivating the pump ?

In my understanding the driver offers an H-bridge setup allowing to control up to two motors in both directions.

Are there any other reasons to prefer this driver instead of a simple MOSFET / Transistor setup with such a simple use case like ours ?

Thank you for your help.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you wish to reverse the direction of the pump without reconnecting the wires in the opposite way, there is no need for a L293. A MOSFET that operates as a switch should be sufficient in your case. You can also try to PWM it and reduce/control the water flow.

Comment: I was considering PWM as well. I will go ahead and do some reading on it :)